# Series function not expanding an expression

Tags: series-expansion, approximation

I have the following code:

```
FDE[d_, η_] := η^(d + 1)/Gamma[d + 2] + π^2/(6*Gamma[d])*η^(d - 1);
Series[FDE[d/t, 1/η]/FDE[d/t - 1, 1/η], {η, 0, 3}]
```

The series function just returns me the expression. But when I put in some numeric value of $d,t$, it actually gives me an expansion. Does it imply, there doesn't exist a general expansion for the expression that I am looking at? Any other way of doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

V 12.1.1. Just add `FullSimplify` to help it

```
 FDE[d_, η_] := η^(d + 1)/Gamma[d + 2] + π^2/(6*Gamma[d])*η^(d - 1);
 Series[FullSimplify[FDE[d/t, 1/η]/FDE[d/t - 1, 1/η]], {η, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Using only `Simplify` gives, on same system the following

```
 Series[Simplify[FDE[d/t, 1/η]/FDE[d/t - 1, 1/η]], {η, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

```
 FullSimplify[%]
```

[image]

Comment: `Series[Simplify[FDE[d/t, 1/\[Eta]]/FDE[d/t - 1, 1/\[Eta]]], {\[Eta], 
  0, 3}]` works for me in version 12.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Something to adjust: `FullSimplify[%]` outputs $$\frac{t}{\eta  (d+t)}+\frac{\pi ^2 d \eta }{3 (d+t)}+\frac{\pi ^4 d^2 \eta ^3 (t-d)}{18 t^2 (d+t)}+O\left(\eta ^4\right). $$